# How to send characters to a virtual serial port in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, serial-port, hyperterminal

Microsoft is very unhelpful, as per [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-happened-hyperterminal#1TC=windows-7).

However one method is the command:

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz > COM3
```

And as per a question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870490/windows-prompt-read-and-send-text-by-com-port), another option is:

```
SerialSend /baudrate 56000 "Send this text"
```

However I'm encountering a bug where not all the data is sent. By playing with the amount of text sent and the chosen baud rate, I've come to the conclusion that while the text is being added to a buffer/queue character by character, the buffer begins being emptied into the serial port, but once the buffer has been filled, the remaining un-sent characters in the buffer are discarded and the command returns.

So I'd like some sort of hyper-terminal equivalent that can send data to the virtual serial port - which hopefully will not have this bug. Can anyone recommend any?

Thanks

Update: `Putty` works, but I cannot output a continuous stream of characters, rather it sends them as I type, one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`TeraTerm` worked. It sends files, is fully configurable e.g. baud rate, stop bits, delays between characters and more.